# setting up and printing out a array variable

Tags: php

Hi I have some simple code here that as far as I can tell should be working but it doesn't and I am puzzled as to why

```
//VARIABLES
$rowcount=15;
$colcount=15;
$path= array( array());
$startrow=8;
$startcol=7;
$row=$startrow;
$col=$startcol;

for ($a=0;$a<$rowcount;$a++) {
    for ($b=0;$b<$colcount;$b++) {
        $path[$a][$b]=0;
    }
}

echo"In case one ";
echo"<BR>";
echo " Col= ".$col;
echo " Row= ".$row-1;
echo " Col= ".$col;
echo " Cell= ".$path[$row-1][$col];
echo " Cellx= ".$path[7][7];
if($path[$row-1][$col]=="o") {
    echo " F1 = ".$flagOne;
        $flagOne="1";
        echo " cell equals ==o==";
        echo " F1 = ".$flagOne;
} else {
    echo " cell not equal ==o==";
}
echo"<BR>";
```

This is what I get as a output

In case one

Col= 7-1 Col= 7 Cell= 0 Cellx= 0 F1 = 0 cell equals ==o== F1 = 1

what puzzles me is the 7th spot "-1"
I would expect to see "Row= 7" not "-1" since $row=8

I have been programming in java and C and lately just barely touching PHP lately but I have been doing PHP for years, I think this should be working

what am i doing wrong

As another issue
looking at the if statement the value of the array/cell = 0 so I would also expect the evaluation to be false and echo this

cell not equal ==o==

but the condition is evaluating true why is this
my one thought is the way I am setting up the $path variable

I simply want it to be a simple two dimensional array $path[$a][$b] is it setup correctly when I output the array I see what I am expecting an two dimensional array.

Never had to do these much in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rowcount=15;
$colcount=15;
$path= array( array());
$startrow=8;
$startcol=7;
$row=$startrow;
$col=$startcol;

for ($a=0;$a<$rowcount;$a++) {
    for ($b=0;$b<$colcount;$b++) {
        $path[$a][$b]=0;
    }
}

echo"In case one ";
echo"<BR>";
echo " Col= ".$col;
echo " Row= ".($row-1);
echo " Col= ".$col;
echo " Cell= ".$path[$row-1][$col];
echo " Cellx= ".$path[7][7];
if($path[$row-1][$col]==0) {
    echo " F1 = ".$flagOne;
        $flagOne="1";
        echo " cell equals ==0==";
        echo " F1 = ".$flagOne;
} else {
    echo " cell not equal ==0==";
}
echo"<BR>";
```

At first, dont use double-quotes all over the script. There is a special meaning to double and single quotes in PHP, read the manual about this. Second - character "o" is not zero. You can clearly see, that You are trying to match zero against lower-case "o". Also, integers does not need to be quoted in PHP just as in about every language out there. Check Your font settings to differ one from another. Third - If You are doing both evaluation and concatenation in PHP, You should surround evaluation statement with parentheses, although it is a bad practice. It is better to pre-calculate values and assign them to values before sending them to output or before concatenating them with another values as strings.

Comment: I was in fact trying to use the lower case letter o In the real output area I was comparing the look of zeros and letter o's when being displayed. This segment of code is actually from a case statement that exchanges a zero for the letter o. (I am using the array like a map.) I did not know about the Parens outside of evaluations when concatenating.